# Filter RDD based on some criteria

Tags: python, filter, rdd

I have one RDD like below -

```
[[u'100=NO', u'101=OR', u'102=-0.00955461556684', u'103=0.799738137456', u'104=-0.619426440691', u'105=-0.505799761741', u'106=1.06018348173', u'107=-0.203731351216', u'108=0.242253668965', u'109=20170411', u'110=14:47:54'], [u'100=NO', u'101=OR', u'102=1.09790894815', u'103=-0.591742622246', u'104=0.60404467739', u'105=-0.729487378829', u'106=-0.41507842821', u'107=-1.01921955205', u'108=-0.153191948561', u'109=20170411', u'110=14:47:56'], [u'100=NO', u'101=OR', u'102=-0.0845031955962', u'103=0.428040384808', u'104=0.0579505934162', u'105=0.893705789837', u'106=-0.544258436965', u'107=1.10990090862', u'108=0.740638990995', u'109=20170411', u'110=14:47:58'], [u'100=NO', u'101=ORCL', u'102=1.20406493416', u'103=-0.275962563807', u'104=-0.728142212616', u'105=2.04751448847', u'106=2.10361125056', u'107=0.588650303087', u'108=-0.693327897822', u'109=20170411', u'110=14:48:00']]
```

I want to remove all characters before "=" symbol from all the indexes of RDD.

I was tried with following example -

```
rdd.filter(lambda x : str(x[6]).split("=",1)[-1])
```

But I want to remove these characters from all the indexes of rdd.

Expected rdd set -

```
[[u'NO', u'OR', u'-0.00955461556684', u'0.799738137456', u'-0.619426440691', u'-0.505799761741', u'1.06018348173', u'-0.203731351216', u'0.242253668965', u'20170411', u'14:47:54'], [u'NO', u'OR', u'1.09790894815', u'-0.591742622246', u'0.60404467739', u'-0.729487378829', u'-0.41507842821', u'-1.01921955205', u'-0.153191948561', u'20170411', u'14:47:56'], [u'NO', u'OR', u'-0.0845031955962', u'0.428040384808', u'0.0579505934162', u'0.893705789837', u'-0.544258436965', u'1.10990090862', u'0.740638990995', u'20170411', u'14:47:58'], [u'100=NO', u'101=ORCL', u'102=1.20406493416', u'-0.275962563807', u'-0.728142212616', u'2.04751448847', u'2.10361125056', u'0.588650303087', u'-0.693327897822', u'20170411', u'14:48:00']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not just filtering as the data must be modified, so `filter` doesn't seems as the appropriate tool.

Try a **nested** *[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)* plus [`sc.parallelize`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html):

```
 RDD = sc.parallelize([[i.split('=')[1] for i in j] for j in RDD.toLocalIterator()])
```

Comment: @klashxx- please see edited given rdd. sorry for wrong assumption.

Comment: @klashxx- I want to remove these characters from all list's indexes from the rdd. one rdd contains many lists like above. Can we use spark's filter approach? **I must want rdd in the output of this result.**

Comment: @klashxx- It is not a list. It is a RDD object and it is not iterable. so your solutions are not satisfied these criteria. Try to use filter method of spark RDD.

Comment: @klashxx- yes right. Is any solution to filter this type of RDD?

Comment: @klashxx Nice Work :) I'm Deleting my answer

Comment: @klashxx- You done it. Thanks for your help. you save my day. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

hello i am new with programming but i think he can solve this also with regex.
 i try something like :

```
import re
test=[[u'100=NO', u'101=OR', u'102=-0.00955461556684', u'103=0.799738137456', u'104=-0.619426440691', u'105=-0.505799761741', u'106=1.06018348173', u'107=-0.203731351216', u'108=0.242253668965', u'109=20170411', u'110=14:47:54'], [u'100=NO', u'101=OR', u'102=1.09790894815', u'103=-0.591742622246', u'104=0.60404467739', u'105=-0.729487378829', u'106=-0.41507842821', u'107=-1.01921955205', u'108=-0.153191948561', u'109=20170411', u'110=14:47:56'], [u'100=NO', u'101=OR', u'102=-0.0845031955962', u'103=0.428040384808', u'104=0.0579505934162', u'105=0.893705789837', u'106=-0.544258436965', u'107=1.10990090862', u'108=0.740638990995', u'109=20170411', u'110=14:47:58'], [u'100=NO', u'101=ORCL', u'102=1.20406493416', u'103=-0.275962563807', u'104=-0.728142212616', u'105=2.04751448847', u'106=2.10361125056', u'107=0.588650303087', u'108=-0.693327897822', u'109=20170411', u'110=14:48:00']]
result = re.sub(r"[u]'\d+", r"", test)
print(result)
```

but it gives a error like: expected string or bytes-like object .
if someone can explain that i would be happy .